# Xcode 8 - Release and Debug builds compile differently

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, restkit, buildconfiguration

We've recently upgraded our iOS-app to `Swift 3` and after a bit of tweaking and debugging, we've managed to make it work. But when we were trying to archive it, we noticed that it doesn't compile in release mode. One of the bugs we've been getting is that in `Debug` mode, `Xcode` wants us to write

```
let client: AFRKHTTPClient = AFRKHTTPClient(baseURL: baseURL.deletingLastPathComponent)
```

while in `Release` mode, we need to write

```
let client: AFRKHTTPClient = AFRKHTTPClient(baseURL: baseURL.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

It seems that the problem with these lines (the others that fail have similar/related issues) is that the `Debug` version attempts to use

```
var deletingLastPathComponent: URL? { get }
```

available from `iOS 4` and up, while the `Release` version tries to use

```
func deletingLastPathComponent() -> URL
```

available from `iOS 10` and up.

Another strange thing about this is that we can call it without parentheses in release, as long as we only build the app not run it.

I've tried cleaning, cleaning build folder, deleting derived data, restarts, with no difference. The same problem also happens on other macs. I've tried going through the the code looking for `RELEASE` or `DEBUG`-tags that could do something, with no luck, as well as setting all (at least I think I got them all) release-settings in the project to the same as the debug-settings, with no luck as well.

We're using `RestKit 0.27.0` and the errors show up around the `RestKit` code, but I can't find anything that should make trouble there either. I'm honestly quite stumped now, so if anyone have any pointers as to where I could search for a fix, they would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the project settings. You probably have differing *base SDK* or *deployment target* settings for debug and release builds. Both types of builds should use the same value.

Comment: @Codo Unfortunately not... Base SDK is Latest iOS for both, while iOS Deployment Target is the same for both too (fails with both 10 and 8.3).

Comment: Check your "Use Legacy Swift ..." build setting. Is it different for Debug and Release configuration?

Comment: @MartinR It is the same for both

Comment: Well, we solved it. It was all our fault and not related to build configurations at all. It seems that the swift3-translate-tool doesn't translate code that's inside C-style macros if it doesn't apply. So an NSUrl was translated to Url in the #ifdef, but not in the #else.